# python: MTCNN is not saving all the files

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision

sap people! im having some troubles making this code work, the point here is that i want to crop the faces of some pictures with the MTCNN lib, then save it as a .jpg file, when i run this code:

```
 # draw each face separately
    def draw_faces(filename, result_list):
        # load the image
        data = pyplot.imread(filename)
        # plot each face as a subplot
        for i in range(len(result_list)):
            # get coordinates
            x1, y1, width, height = result_list[i]['box']
            x2, y2 = x1 + width, y1 + height
            # define subplot
            pyplot.subplot(1, len(result_list), i+1)
            pyplot.axis('off')
            # plot face
            pyplot.imshow(data[y1:y2, x1:x2])
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            pyplot.imwrite(justfaces+name+'/'+file, )
        # show the plot
        pyplot.show()


for name in names:
    onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(os.path.join(ALL_DATA,name)) ]
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(justfaces,name))
    for file in onlyfiles:
        filename = '%s/%s' % (ALL_DATA+name, file)
        # load image from file
        pixels = pyplot.imread(filename)
        # create the detector, using default weights
        detector = MTCNN()
        #detect faces in the image
        faces = detector.detect_faces(pixels)
        print(faces)
        # display faces on the original image
        draw_faces(filename, faces)
```

the code work as it should but in some point i get this error

```
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

now the problem i think is that there is a picture w/o persons, so there is no faces to write and some for loop is making this error showing up, if any of you could helpme i will be so grateful, in advance thank you for reading

edit:
i was looking the json returned from the draw_face just before it promt the error it looks like this

```
[{'box': [170, -22, 177, 242], 'confidence': 0.9992941617965698, 'keypoints': {'left_eye': (227, 62), 'right_eye': (305, 73), 'nose': (257, 110), 'mouth_left': (220, 151), 'mouth_right': (288, 162)}}]
```

something interesting is the -22 in the second entry of box, this could be the cause of the error? if this is the case, do you any idea how to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here i am, the solution of this problem as far as i can understand is this:

the mtncc is bugged, as the github issue claims ( https://github.com/ipazc/mtcnn/issues/11 ) some times it gets the coordinates to be negative, so i decide to make some changes, actually just turn x and y = 0 if they were negative, for now this solve my problem here is the code =3

```
#cropeo de caras y creacion de nueva carpeta para solo caras
names = [l for l in listdir(TOP_DATA) if os.path.isdir(join(TOP_DATA,l)) ]
# draw each face separately
def draw_faces(filename, result_list):
    # load the image
    data = pyplot.imread(filename)
    # plot each face as a subplot
    k = 1
    for i in range(len(result_list)):
        # get coordinates
        x1, y1, width, height = result_list[i]['box']
        x2, y2 = x1 + width, y1 + height
        if x1 <0:
            x1=0
        if x2 <0:
            x2=0
        if y1 <0:
            y1=0
        if y2 <0:
            y2=0
        # save face
        lalala = cvtColor(data[y1:y2, x1:x2], COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        outfile = '%s/%s_%s' % (FACES+name, k, file)
        imwrite(outfile,lalala)
        k +=k
for name in names:
    onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(os.path.join(TOP_DATA,name)) ]
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(FACES,name))
    for file in onlyfiles:
        filename = '%s/%s' % (TOP_DATA+name, file)
        # load image from file
        pixels = pyplot.imread(filename)
        # create the detector, using default weights
        detector = MTCNN()
        #detect faces in the image
        faces = detector.detect_faces(pixels)
        # display faces on the original image
        draw_faces(filename, faces)
```